# After running command, "phablet-flash ubuntu-system --no-backup" Responds: "unsupported device"

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want to try the new Ubuntu system for Android phones.

The step by step goes as said on the web page http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/install

Everything ran smoothly until I ran the command:

`phablet-flash ubuntu-system --no-backup`

I received the message,

```
WARNING:phablet-flash:--no-backup is depreciated, use --bootstrap instead

INFO:phablet-flash:Device detected as sanstar15_ics2

ERROR:phablet-flash:unsupported device, autodetect fails device
```

I received this phone from my grandmother, which I know has homebrew elements to it which the previous owner, before my grandmother, has obviously added to the device.

So I figured to remove the previous system on it and add a different system to it.

I saw how the Ubuntu Edge is out for testing and this phone would prove to be a great test subject.

I believe that the phone is probably made by someone who is not a major company, such as Samsung, and the phone may or may not be up to par.

When I open the phone's build.prop, to my surprise I find this:

> ro.build.type=user
>
> ro.build.user=root
>
> ro.build.host=ubuntu
>
> ro.build.tags=test-keys
>
> ro.product.model=GT-N7100
>
> ro.product.brand=samsung
>
> ro.product.name=sanstar15_ics2
>
> ro.product.device=sanstar15_ics2
>
> ro.product.board=sanstar15_ics2
>
> ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
>
> ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
>
> ro.product.manufacturer=samsung
>
> ro.product.locale.language=en
>
> ro.product.locale.region=US

I think this tells me that the creator of this phone may have been just creating a fake phone?  and the part where it says `ro.build.host=ubuntu`  is the system on it really ubuntu?

I have so many questions and I await a response.

*edit*

OK.  So it's not supported...  But there are many elements I have questions for.   First off, the phone has a setting to choose from which of the two sim cards to use.  And then the prop editor built into it can make the phone say it's something that its not.  Such as swapping the build.prop with the prop of another device,  by just bluetooth detection.  It has an extended antenna that sticks out for extended range, I'm assuming.  It has 16Gb of space.  It has a separate memory space For the system.  It even has 2gigs of swap that isn't on the 16 gigs of space.  The screen resolution sucks and the camera sucks too.  But the cpu power is crazy.  It claims it has 1.5ghz and 1024mb of ram.  I could run three game boys and game link them via bluetooth to this phone as the server while using bluetooth connection to a wiimote for a controller while running Spotify.  It has 2 headphone jacks and 2 mini USB ports.  One port is in plain sight while the other is underneath the battery cover.   It is an interesting thing

sent by my Pantech Flex, P8010

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but your phone is **not supported** by Ubuntu for phones.

From your build.prop:

```
...
ro.product.model=GT-N7100
...
```

The model *GT-N7100* is more popularly known as the *Galaxy Note II*. The *Note* is currently **not** supported by Ubuntu for phones.

At the moment, only two phones are supported by Ubuntu for phones: the *Galaxy Nexus* and the *Nexus 4*. NThis does not include the *Note*. [Source](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/install)

Answer (score 1):

Your phone is unsupported.

Without knowing the make and model, my best guess is that's it's running a single-core processor, or the total RAM is too small.